# Plone 4.3 - image_view suddenly wants me to login

Tags: view, permissions, plone

Whenever I upload an Image (DAV or HTML) to my Plone site, the image gets uploaded and created. I can refer to the image and it shows up in the folders "gallery" view.

But, when I access that image to view it, Plone says that I have no permissons for the context (as admin).

I know this behavior from errors in custom templates, but I did't touch the image_view at all.

The error_log of this instance (in debug mode) shows no trace whatsoever.

I've rebuilt the catalog with no success.

Where can one view and/or set the permissions for `image_view`?

**UPDATE**

OK, must be theme related?! When I uninstall my theme, everything works.

**UPDATE II**

It is the theme. Specifically the `theme_base`. Whenever I install my theme in Plone, I see `plonetheme.mytheme` as `theme_base`. When I switch this to `Sunburst Theme` the image_view works again, but everything else doesn't.

My `skins.xml` should be ok though:

```
<object name="mytheme_custom"
    meta_type="Filesystem Directory View"
    directory="plonetheme.mytheme:skins/mytheme_custom"/>
<skin-path name="plonetheme.mytheme" based-on="Sunburst Theme">
<layer name="mytheme_custom"
    insert-after="custom"/>
</skin-path>
```

The theme was done following [this tutorial](http://docs.plone.org/4/en/adapt-and-extend/theming/theme_product_with_diazo.html#create-a-product-to-handle-your-diazo-theme)

**UPDATE III**

After removing `Unauthorized` from `error_log` in ZMI (thanks to @mathias), I was able to trace down and fix a problematic line in my `main_template.pt`. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: View permissions are usually set in ZCML. Is the website online, can we have a look? Is the theme code available in some public repo?

Comment: For better debug infos, please remove `Unauthrorized` from the ignored exceptions in the `error_log` (ZMI). Also make shure, debug mode and verbose security is on. Security implementation should be python. Now should see whats exactly wrong.

Comment: @Mathias Yes, thanks, I'll do that and update my question. Although I feel, it might have to do with either skin_layers or the IThemeSpecific marker interface beeing broken/buggy.

Comment: @ansi_lumen I added my comment also as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment was the answer for this question I add it also as an answer.

> For better debug infos, please remove Unauthrorized (Exception) from the ignored exceptions in the error_log (ZMI).
>
> Also make sure, debug mode and verbose security is on.
>
> Security implementation should be python.
>
> If you now trigger the error, you should see what's wrong.